# Use PDFView as default AucTex PDF Viewer

Tags: auctex, pdf-tools

I'd like to use PDFView mode as the default PDF reader when editing LaTeX code in AucTeX, using Emacs 24. For example, after compiling with C-c C-c, redoing this command would open the PDF file in a second buffer in the same window, using PDFView mode instead of Doc View.

Answer (score 4):

I just set this up yesterday so all you need in your init file is.

```
 ;; to use pdfview with auctex
 (setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "PDF Tools"))
    TeX-view-program-list '(("PDF Tools" TeX-pdf-tools-sync-view))
    TeX-source-correlate-start-server t) ;; not sure if last line is neccessary

 ;; to have the buffer refresh after compilation
 (add-hook 'TeX-after-compilation-finished-functions
        #'TeX-revert-document-buffer)
```

You can also use  <kbd>C-c C-a</kbd> to compile and view at the same time. It also compiles bibtech if applicable. Its faster to press than  <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>  <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>. I ended up inverting the two keybindings

#### Update 1:

In respons to: why is `tex-view-program-list` not defined for me?

That variable is defined in the `auctex` package. It is essentially essential to using latex in emacs.

If it is not installed you should `package-install auctex` and then place `(require 'latex)`.  <s>if you use `use-package` you can add</s>

```
(use-package tex-site
  :ensure auctex
  :init
  (require 'latex)
  ;; to use pdfview with auctex
  (setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "PDF Tools"))
        TeX-view-program-list '(("PDF Tools" TeX-pdf-tools-sync-view))
        TeX-source-correlate-start-server t) ;; not sure if last line is neccessary

  ;; to have the buffer refresh after compilation
  (add-hook 'TeX-after-compilation-finished-functions
            #'TeX-revert-document-buffer))
```

#### Update 2: Strikeout due to suggestion in comments

Comment: I've already tried something like that, but the problem is that I don't have any function or variable named _TeX-pdf-tools-sync-view_, so this doesn't work at all. Do you know why I don't have this name?

Comment: I edited my answer with more information

Comment: Yes I'm using AucTex, installed through apt-get.

Comment: Do you have `(require 'latex)` in your init file?

Comment: @JulesTamagnan Where did you find the line `(require 'latex)`?  It should be never used explicitly.  @Spirine install AUCTeX with Emacs package manager, don't use the outdated version present in repository of your distribution.

Comment: I didn't find it so much as realized that it worked. What would be a better way to use latex and use-package? I struggled to get it to work any other way. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @giordano I've installed the Melpa version of Auctex and now it workds! Thank you